# При открытии нового окна крашится программа

Tags: qt5, qtcreator

QT 5.10(В QT сreator) Программа работает нормально, до тех пор, пока не открываю новое окно, тогда вылетает. Удалось выяснить, что проблема появляется, когда я создаю новый объект класса, реализующего это окно(класс costwindow).Если что, то программа выполняет задачу конфигуратора тура. Помогите пожалуйста.
P.S При создании меню перепутал пункты doezd и hotel, поэтому в пункте doezd реализован показ цены отеля, а в пункте hotel - доезд.
Mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QMessageBox>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~MainWindow();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();

void on_doezd_triggered();

void on_hotel_triggered();

void on_cost_triggered();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp
`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "costwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
int res(0),coef(0);
if(ui->ComboBoxDays->currentIndex() == 0)
{
    coef = 2;
}else{
    coef = 4;
}
switch(ui->comboBoxDoezd->currentIndex())
{
case 0:
    res += 3500 * coef;
    break;
case 1:
    res += 5200 * coef;
    break;
case 2:
    res += 56700 * coef;
    break;
case 3:
    res += 62000 * coef;
    break;
}
switch(ui->comboBoxHotel->currentIndex())
{
case 0:
    res += 4900 * coef;
    break;
case 1:
    res += 4600 * coef;
    break;
case 2:
    res += 4000 * coef;
    break;
case 3:
    res += 2000 * coef;
    break;
case 4:
    res += 1900 * coef;
    break;
}
if(ui->comboBoxTransport->currentIndex() == 0)
{
    res += 500 * coef;
}
ui->reslabel->setNum(res);
}


void MainWindow::on_doezd_triggered()
{
bool diares = false;
QString sel = QInputDialog::getItem(this,"Отель","Выберите вариант",
   QStringList() << "Гостиница Кайзерхоф" << "Отель Обертайх Люкс" <<          "Гостиница Лангендорф" << "Гостиница Фридрихсхоф" << "Гостиница Пруссия",
   0,false,&diares);
if(diares)
{
    int cost;
 if(sel == QString("Гостиница Кайзерхоф"))
 {
  cost = 4900;
 }else if(sel == QString("Отель Обертайх Люкс"))
 {
  cost = 4600;
 }else if(sel == QString("Гостиница Лангендорф"))
 {
  cost = 4000;
 }else if(sel == QString("Гостиница Фридрихсхоф"))
 {
  cost = 2000;
 }else{
     cost = 1900;
 }
 QMessageBox::information(this,sel,"Цена: " + QString::number(cost));
}
}

void MainWindow::on_hotel_triggered()
{
bool diares = false;
QString sel = QInputDialog::getItem(this,"Доезд","Выберите вариант",
   QStringList() << "Победа эконом" << "Урал эйрлайнс эконом" << "Урал
 эйрлайнс бизнес" << "Аэрофлот бизнес",
   0,false,&diares);
   if(diares)
    {
    int cost;
    if(sel == QString("Победа эконом"))
 {
  cost = 3500;
 }else if(sel == QString("Урал эйрлайнс эконом"))
 {
  cost = 5200;
 }else if(sel == QString("Урал эйрлайнс бизнес"))
 {
  cost = 56700;
 }else{
  cost = 62000;
 }
 QMessageBox::information(this,sel,"Цена: " + QString::number(cost));
}
}

void MainWindow::on_cost_triggered()
{
Ui::costwindow * wind = new Ui::costwindow(this);//от этого программа
//крашится.
this->hide();
wind->exec();
}
```

`
costwindow.h

```
#ifndef COSTWINDOW_H
#define COSTWINDOW_H
#include <QDialog>
#include <QApplication>
namespace Ui{
class costwindow : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit costwindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~costwindow();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
costwindow *ui;
};
}
#endif // COSTWINDOW_H
```

costwindow.cpp

```
#include "costwindow.h"
#include "ui_costwindow.h"
using namespace Ui;
costwindow::costwindow(QWidget *parent):
QDialog(parent)
{
ui = new costwindow;
}
costwindow::~costwindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void Ui::costwindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
this->hide();
}
```

main.cpp содержит только автоматически сгенерированный код.

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

У вас рекурсивный вызов конструктора `costwindow`, сжирающий всю память и роняющий программу. Можете убедиться, добавив перед `ui = new costwindow;` что-то типа `qDebug() << "call constructor";`.

Советую прочитать у Макса Шлее, как правильно подключать графические интерфейсы в класс.